# Only one hotkey does not work since today! XP chrome

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey, windows-xp-sp3

Hello I am using autohotkey for more than a year with 4 diffent keys.

```
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

F1::send, {ctrl down}ψ{ctrl up} 
F2::send, {ctrl down}ω{ctrl up} 
F3::send, {alt down}{tab down}{tab up}{alt up}
F4::send, {alt down}{shift down}{shift up}{alt up}
```

F1 and F2 is copy and paste respectively, F2 change window, F4 change language layout.

Everything worked like a charm till today that the only thing doesn't work is F4 in chrome. everywhere else it is working and the other 3 (F1 F2 F3) hotkeys work fine in chrome. What cahnged is the version of chrome.

Also if I try to hit manually alt shift the layout works perfect.
I have not administrator account. I tried to assign it to the ` and it is the same. It works everywhere but chrome.

Any ideas? I use it for my work and it is annoying!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try and run your script as admin

If that works check this out https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/70449-enable-interaction-with-administrative-programs/

Comment: I have no admin privileges at this computer.

Comment: Most likely chrome has a use for F4 and if your privileges are lower than chrome's you're at a loss

Comment: one thing you can try is to install the keyboard hook https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InstallKeybdHook.htm

Comment: I don't know if privileges changed with the updated chrome. What I have to do with the keyboard hook?